# BPF filters in multithreaded application

Tags: linux, libpcap, bpf

I have a multi-threaded(2 threads) application which use BPF filters , where in each thread uses a PF_PACKET socket and tries to apply a BPF filter using SO_ATTACH_FILTER on the same incoming interface.
But what i observe is that both the threads are receiving all the packets matching both the filters rather than each thread receiving only for the filter they have added.
Is this how it is suppose to work or should i do anything else explicitly to achieve this kind of filtering ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add a minimal example code to your question so we can help?

Comment: I'm writing a sample application to demonstrate the same would post it here as soon as i have it.

Comment: I figured out it was not an issue with BPF filtering but it was something in my application so i'm good with it now.

Comment: You can remove this question then as it serves no purpose ;)

Comment: Or you can answer your own question, so anybody else seeing that issue can see how you fixed the problem.